# Send value from Javascript to servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, servlets

Hi i have this code here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var clickCount = {}
aList = document.getElementsByTagName('a')

clickCounter = function()
{
    clickCount[this.href] = clickCount[this.href] ? clickCount[this.href]+1 : 1;
}
```

// The event is attached to every link having a "href" attribute

```
for (var i=0 ; i<aList.length, a=aList[i] ; i++)
{
if (this.href)
{
a.onclick = clickCounter;
}
}
```

I need to send this to a servlet so that i can store the value on a database, i found this example for PHP, but don't know how to do it for a Servlet. And also how can i get the value to the Servlet?

// This example uses jQuery to send the data to a PHP script
// A POST request is sent just before the window is closed

```
onbeforeunload = function()
{
$.post('/tracking.php', clickCount);
}
}
```

The objective of the program, is to count downloads and store the in a database using JSP.

Comment: The same but instead of `tracking.php` use the servlet name. You can access the parameters using `HttpServletRequest`'s `getParameter`.

Comment: counting downloads with javascript might bringt you wrong result.
Direct links and disabled javascript for example.
You could improve that by counting them without any clientside code involved

Comment: so how should i count them? since i still have to store the counter on  a mysql database.